# Java - NullPointerException when parsing JSON despite getOrDefault

Tags: java, json, collections

I'm trying to parse JSON and decided to use getOrDefault to deal with null values. According to the doc: `Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or defaultValue if this map contains no mapping for the key.`

However when it's parsing the following line from JSON - `"theDate": null` I'm getting a `NullPointerException` . While debugging I noticed that `String 
 dateFromJson` is `null` despite the `getOrDefault` call. But I expected it to have a default String value.

What could be wrong with my implementation and understanding here?

```
public static Long parseDate(JSONObject jsonObj, String date, String _default) throws ParseException {
    String dateFromJson = (String) jsonObj.getOrDefault(date, _default);
    if (Objects.equals(dateFromJson, _default)) {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();        
    }
    return DATE_FORMAT.parse(dateFromJson).getTime();
}
```

Comment: and what is the value of `default`?

Comment: which line is the Exception being created? what is in `date`?  `dateFromJson` must be `null` since that is the value of `"theDate"` (assuming `data == "theDate"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you explicitly have `"theDate": null` in your json, the `JSONObject` will contain the entry `{key=theDate, value=null}`, and when you call `getOrDefault()`, since the key is contained within the `JSONObject` (that is essentially a specialized map), your default value will not be used. Since you get the exception from last line, it is easy to deduce `_default` is not null, otherwise `Objects.equals(dateFromJson, _default)` would be true and if condition would've returned the method.

You'd need to do;

```
String result = Optional.ofNullable(jsonObj.get(date)).orElse(_default);
```

Since either key is contained with null value, or there is no key, you'd get `null` in both cases. So better to just cover this possibility with `Optional`, or better to use;

```
String result = ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(jsonObj.get(date), _default)
```

if you have `apache lang3` as your dependency.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have understood `Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or defaultValue if this map contains no mapping for the key.` in the wrong way. Basically it means that if in the input model there is no such a property with a `key=String date` then the default value will be returned. But if there is a property you are looking for but its value is `null` then this `null` will be returned. Isn't so?